# Slow recursive code to find roots of an equation

Tags: python, recursion

I have recursive Python code to find the roots of an equation. 
For some reason, it doesn't run for big numbers of iterations such as n=100.

I want to know what's wrong in this code. Why is it very slow?

```
import os    
import sympy as sy    
from sympy.solvers import solve    
from sympy import Symbol    
x = Symbol('x')    
from sympy import *    
n=100    
def ene(j):    
    if j<0:    
            return 0    
    elif 0<=j<2:    
            return 1        
    elif 2<=j<4:    
            return N(simplify(ene(j-2)*(4*j-6-x))/(j*(j-1)))    
    elif 4<=j<6:    
            return N(simplify((ene(j-2)*(4*j-6-x))-3*ene(j-4))/(j*(j-1)))    
    elif 6<=j<n+1:    
            return N(simplify((ene(j-2)*(4*j-6-x))+ene(j-6)-3*ene(j-4))/(j*(j-1)))     

d=ene(n)    
print(d)    
root=(sy.solve(d,x))    
print(root)    
aa=str(root)    
with open('newEnergyvalue3.txt', 'wt') as energy:    
    energy.writelines(aa)    
print('finished')    
energy.close()
```

Comment: Do you have an error?

Comment: No. It doesn't have an error. But take long time to run.

Comment: Of course it goes long, in elif 6<=j<n+1 you have 3 calls of the same function. Did you see this https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Numerical_Methods/Roots_of_Equations.
You have about 3^100 = 5.15377521 × 10^47 operations

Comment: I'm very beginner of the Python. Can't I use different libraries to find roots of the  equation

Comment: Where did you get your code?

Comment: I did it myself. Do you know any easy method to call recursive function and find roots.